# How to update user model from api in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

I am new to rails and i want to produce json response for iPhone app from server. I have user model where they can get the current user information after login using the token

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept:
>   application/json'   -X GET htt://localhost:3000/profile.json  -d
>   "{"user" : { "auth_token" : "asjyWYeyVHDJrg746h" }}"

this provides the user information, similarly how can the user be edited or updated by passing the values that are to be changed.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape). Also read about `respond_to :json`